# How to know which commit belongs to which branch

Tags: git

When I use `git log --graph` (or my alias for it) how can I tell which commit (*) belongs to which branch?

Here's my gitconfig

```
tree = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --format=format:'%C(boldblue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(black)%s%C(reset)%C(dim black)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all
```

Any help would rock!

**Update**
I ended up using: 
    git log --all --graph --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) %C(dim black)%s%C(reset)%C(bold red)%d%C(reset) %C(green)by %an, %ar%C(reset)'

Comment: Which version of Git are you using?

Comment: @Cupcake: does this matter? I think such basic tasks should be version independent.

Comment: @CommuSoft yes it does matter, some `git log` format options only work in certain versions of Git, for example, the `%d` decoration format.

Comment: I agree, but I thought the name of the branch should be implemented in all the modern versions of `git`.

Comment: I'm on git version 1.8.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just use `git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate`.

Git rearranges this graph as you make commits to always show merges coming in from the right toward the left. You can always tell what's a branch, and where it's merging because of this, even when it starts to get all twisty. Here's an example snippet from one of my repos, as output by the above log command:

```
| * af8bb24 Remove mayaaxis.py
| * 39b27d7 Remove axis.py
|/  
*   a12c712 Merge branch 'MayaObject'
|\  
| * 755c024 Elide pymel.core.animation import in core.py
| * 6de87c2 Clean up imports in core.py
| * 4b70adf Move core.RefGrid to new grid.py
| *   40d3c7d Merge branch 'absorbMayaRef' into MayaObject
| |\  
| | * 58305e5 Add core.MayaObject test for refFile property
| | * 154af30 Refactor core.MayaObject refPath to refFile
| | * d23fe77 Condense namespace work in core.MayaRef.loadRef
| | * 22c780b Add missing test for core.MayaRef namespace arg
| |/  
| * 6843970 Remove projPath arg from core.MayaRef constructor
| * 692578a Add docstrings to core.MayaObject test classes
| * acb4d75 Add core.MayaObject init defaults test
| * b8f1ae6 Stub in core.MayaObject
|/  
* 4dc6112 Make __init__.py imports relative
* abde256 Add *.swp, and *.swo to .gitignore
```

Note the `a12c712` commit near the top - that's a merge of the former 'MayaObject' branch, which started near bottom at the `4dc6112` commit. You can see it branch off to the right at the bottom, and merge back in to the left near the top. The first commit on the 'MayaObject' branch was `b8f1ae6`, which forks off to the right - branching always goes off to the right, merging always comes in toward the left.

You can also see that while I was on the 'MayaObject' branch, I decided to jump off again and work on the 'absorbMayaRef' branch, which forked off of `6843970`, and it's first commit was `22c780b`. It merged back into 'MayaObject' at `40d3c7d`, and then 'MayaObject' - as stated at the beginning - merged back into the master branch at `a12c712`.

Leave the auto-generated merge commit messages (e.g. "Merge branch 'absorbMayaRef' into MayaObject") intact, and you'll always be able to tell what belonged to which branch. If you delete or overwrite those messages when making merge commits, then you will not be able to tell what was on which branch.

I always make it clear in my commits what I touched, because it's usually some small change in one file. Note how the 4 commits from `22c780b` to `58305e5`, inclusive, all mention 'core.MayaRef' or 'core.MayaObject'. Even if I didn't have the `40d3c7d` merge telling me that was the 'absorbMayaRef' branch, I'd still be able to see pretty quickly that that feature branch had to do with something in the core module, and with those 2 classes in particular. When my changes touch a bunch of files, I try to make that clear, and note in general what happened in the change, e.g. "Refactor path names across library", or "Reorganize tests in several test files".

Comment: I use `git config alias.lgdo '!git log --graph --decorate --oneline ${@---all}'` -- it defaults to `--all` but defers to me.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need `git log`?

Again `tig` denotes this in a nicer way: the name of the branch is denoted between square brackets on the right of the first commit.

You install `tig` using `sudo apt-get install tig`, next you make the root of the repository your current directory and run `tig`.

The screen will show three groups of columns: the first containing information about the commit (date and author), the second will show an ASCII art of the tree and the third will provide messages.

`tig` also denotes the type of the commit (initial (`I`)/commit (`O`) and merge (`M`)) in the tree. Tags are denoted in purple, branch heads in cyan and branch heads of remotes in orange.

Sometimes not all branches are displayed (if the number is too large). In that case you can run `tig --all`

A more detailed manual is available here: http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/manual.html

Comment: Okay, how do I use tig?

Comment: one moment, I will rewrite my answer.

Comment: I hope this short introduction is sufficient? You can also run `man tig` for a more extended introduction.

Answer (score 2):

To look at the git history in X you can use `gitk` (part of the vanilla git suite, might be a separate package in your distribution). There are several git graphical front ends for git too.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using: git log --all --graph --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) %C(dim black)%s%C(reset)%C(bold red)%d%C(reset) %C(green)by %an, %ar%C(reset)'